# How to make list of cars into string?

Tags: python

Please help with this function:

```
def car_list_as_string(cars: list) -> str:
    """
    Create a list of cars.
    The order of the elements in the string is the same as in the list.

    [['Audi', ['A4']], ['Skoda', ['Superb']]] =>
    "Audi A4,Skoda Superb"
    """
```

I tried this, but it's unfinished... got stuck.

```
for car in cars:
    print(car)
    cars2 = ''.join(str(car) for car in cars)
    print(cars2)
    one_car = str(car[0])
    print(one_car)
    one_model = str(car[1])
    print(one_model)
```

Input is:

```
[['Audi', ['A4']], ['Skoda', ['Superb']]]
```

Output should be:

```
"Audi A4,Skoda Superb"
```

Comment: It would possibly make more sense to first convert the list into a dict, with the key being the brand, and the value being a list of models. I think it makes viewing and thinking about the data easier. The current structure is less sensible, in my opinion.

Comment: Do you always have one model per manufacturer? Or can there be something like `['Skoda', ['Superb', 'Octavia']]`?

Comment: @9769953 Assuming the given task, conversion is redundant and wouldn't make the implementation easier.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Indeed. I was mostly pointing out a problem with the existing data structure, which is a bad one for the data at hand. Hence it's just a comment. Though for fun, my suggested answer does use that conversion to dict anyway.

Comment: @9769953 Why is the list bad? Why is dict preferable?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych With a dict, I can instantly find all models belonging to the same brand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a code who also work for multiple nested models:

```
def car_list_as_string(cars: list):
    output_list: list[str] = []

    for brand, models in cars:
        for model in models:
            output_list.append(f"{brand} {model}")

    cars_string = ",".join(output_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

For badly readable one-liners, this can work:

```
", ".join(f"{brand} {model}" for brand, models in dict(cars).items() for model in models)
```

Comment: As I mention in the comment converting to the dictionary is redundant. Even in your code `for brand, models in dict(cars).items()` would be equivalent to just `for brand, models in cars`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, this is one approach to make your list of cars into string

```
def car_list_as_string(cars: list) -> str:
    car_names = []
    for car in cars:
        car_names.append(f"{car[0]} {car[1][0]}")
    return ", ".join(car_names)
```

Comment: Thanks! Also what if the list is [['Audi', ['A4', 'A6']], ['Skoda', ['Superb']]] so the same car  has 2 models?

Comment: @medprogram that this becomes not a complete answer, the same as mine does actually, since indexing is number based, not variable based

Comment: As per the input he mentioned, it does but for nested lists it will be little different then.

Answer (score 1):

- iterate over makes and models at once using a `for` loop
- construct the full names and append them to a `list`
- join the list into a single string

```py
def car_list_as_string(cars: list) -> str:
    car_names = []
    for make, models in cars:
        car_names.append(' '.join([make, models[0]]))
    return ", ".join(car_names)
```

Or to avoid indexing as Yevhen Kuzmovych suggested:

```py
def car_list_as_string(cars: list) -> str:
    car_names = []
    for make, (model,) in cars:
        car_names.append(' '.join([make, model]))
    return ", ".join(car_names)
```

The `(model,)` syntax means "unpack the 2nd element into a one element tuple".

Comment: You could also do something like `for make, (model,) in cars:` to avoid indexing.

Comment: Yep, matter of preference what is more readable, but I'll update my answer, thanks

Comment: There was a missing closing parentheses, it should work now after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this depends on **exactly** what the output should look like if the input data are slightly different to that shown in the question.

The data look like this:

```
data = [['Audi', ['A4']], ['Skoda', ['Superb']]]
```

This is interesting because there's no apparent reason for the model designation to be in a list. The implication is that the data might look something like this:

```
data = [['Audi', ['A4', 'Series II']], ['Skoda', ['Superb']]]
```

So let's allow for that construct...

```
def process(_list):
    return ','.join(' '.join([make] + model) for make, model in _list)

print(process(data))
```

**Output:**

```
Audi A4 Series II, Skoda Superb
```